# How to store PHP files in cloud for Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, http

I am new to Android Development. I created an Android application. My Android application can access data from a `MySQl` database. I stored my `php` files in the local machine's htdocs folder. I am able to access the data using the `HttpClient` and `HttpPost`.

I wanted to know if there is any possibility that i can store just the PHP files in the cloud and access the client's database (client web server).

Android App ------> PHP (cloud) -------> MySQL.

Thanks,

Comment: Why would you host the database on your own computer unless this app was for your own personal use....?

Comment: I think you're not only new to android development but also software develop in general. No offence but the whole idea is rather crazy...either ways I'm highlighting below for your own info, but really you should do some research and most importantly document yourself. Don't touch any development tools until you really understand how computer, device and network systems work

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to know if there is any possibility that i can store just the
> PHP files in the cloud and access the database (in my local machine)

Yes, it is technically achievable. However, if you are planning to deploy this app to a market place such as Google Play, the idea is rather crazy for a number of reasons...

1. Your local computer will not probably be reliable enough to handle a considerable high traffic
2. Your local computer and local infrastructure is not probably scalable
3. It's pointless having a site in a highly available and scalable platform such as a cloud system while having its backend database in local dev computer. Really, what's the point? It's like fitting a V8 Engine on a push bike
4. I could go on and mention stuff like security, bandwith, workload, etc...

> My Andriod application can access data from a MySQl database. I stored my php files in the local machine's htdocs folder

This is a bit confusing. Is your application accessing PHP pages, MySQL db or both.

#### Pointers

1. If your app's UI is based on HTML you can easily bundle the html files with the apk...there are a lot of development tools out there that leverage the process of developing cross-platform html5 apps...PhoneGap is one of the most popular ones
2. Consider using a SQLite database and bundle it with the apk
3. If none of these are options for you...mate, at least move the MySql database to the cloud as well. But, believe me, your app will be almost unusable if every action requires a network call which is a pretty bad user experience